# How can put multiple plots side-by-side in shiny r?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny

In mainpanel, I try to handle this problem via fluidrow. However, one of my plot is optional to be displayed or not by users. When user clicks the button, the second plot appears below the first plot.

```
   fluidRow(
      column(2, align="right",
             plotOutput(outputId = "plotgraph1", width  = "500px",height = "400px"),  
             plotOutput(outputId = "plotgraph2", width  = "500px",height = "400px")
      ))
```

I played with "align" and "widths", but nothing changed.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

So it is a couple years later, and while the others answers - including mine -  are still valid, it is not how I would recommend approaching it today. Today I would lay it out using the `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package.

- It allows any number of plots, and can lay them out in a grid checkerboard-like. (I was erroneously under the impression `splitLayout` only worked with two).
- It has more customization possibilities (you can specify rows, columns, headers, footer, padding, etc.)
- It is ultimately easier to use, even for two plots, since laying out in the UI is finicky - it can be difficult to predict what Bootstrap will do with your elements when the screen size changes.
- Since this question gets a lot of traffic, I kind of think more alternative should be here.

The `cowplot` package is also worth looking into, it offers similar functionality, but I am not so familiar with it.

Here is a small shiny program demonstrating that:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

u <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel"),
  sidebarLayout(position = "left",
      sidebarPanel("sidebar panel",
           checkboxInput("donum1", "Make #1 plot", value = T),
           checkboxInput("donum2", "Make #2 plot", value = F),
           checkboxInput("donum3", "Make #3 plot", value = F),
           sliderInput("wt1","Weight 1",min=1,max=10,value=1),
           sliderInput("wt2","Weight 2",min=1,max=10,value=1),
           sliderInput("wt3","Weight 3",min=1,max=10,value=1)
      ),
      mainPanel("main panel",
          column(6,plotOutput(outputId="plotgraph", width="500px",height="400px"))
))))

s <- shinyServer(function(input, output) 
{
  set.seed(123)
  pt1 <- reactive({
    if (!input$donum1) return(NULL)
    qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("red"),binwidth=0.2,main="plotgraph1")
    })
  pt2 <- reactive({
    if (!input$donum2) return(NULL)
    qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("blue"),binwidth=0.2,main="plotgraph2")
  })
  pt3 <- reactive({
    if (!input$donum3) return(NULL)
    qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("green"),binwidth=0.2,main="plotgraph3")
  })
  output$plotgraph = renderPlot({
    ptlist <- list(pt1(),pt2(),pt3())
    wtlist <- c(input$wt1,input$wt2,input$wt3)
    # remove the null plots from ptlist and wtlist
    to_delete <- !sapply(ptlist,is.null)
    ptlist <- ptlist[to_delete] 
    wtlist <- wtlist[to_delete]
    if (length(ptlist)==0) return(NULL)

    grid.arrange(grobs=ptlist,widths=wtlist,ncol=length(ptlist))
  })
})
shinyApp(u,s)
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: Does `grid.arrange` work with `renderPlotly` on two out of five plots in the mainpanel?

Answer (score 60):

Using @Mike Wise example, you can also use splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%")...to show two plots side by side.

ui..R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel"),

  sidebarLayout(position = "left",
                sidebarPanel("sidebar panel",
                             checkboxInput("do2", "Make 2 plots", value = T)
                ),
                mainPanel("main panel",
                          fluidRow(
                            splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), plotOutput("plotgraph1"), plotOutput("plotgraph2"))
                          )
                )
  )
)
)
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) 
{
  set.seed(1234)
  pt1 <- qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("red"),binwidth=0.2,title="plotgraph1")
  pt2 <- reactive({
    input$do2
    if (input$do2){
      return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("blue"),binwidth=0.2,title="plotgraph2"))
    } else {
      return(NULL)
    }
  })
  output$plotgraph1 = renderPlot({pt1})
  output$plotgraph2 = renderPlot({pt2()})
}
)
```

you can also play with the numbers the figure below shows c("60%", "40%")

[image]

EDIT: It is true that @Mike Wise new answer's gives some flexibility. But `splitLayout` can also be used with more than two plots. Using `cellWidths` allows you to change the size of each individual plot. And `verticalLayout()` can also be used to add plots vertically (see comment section).

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
u<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel"),

  sidebarLayout(position = "left",
                sidebarPanel("sidebar panel",
                             checkboxInput("do2", "Make 2 plots", value = T)
                ),
                mainPanel("main panel",
                          fluidRow(
                            splitLayout(style = "border: 1px solid silver:", cellWidths = c(300,200,100), 
                            plotOutput("plotgraph1"), 
                            plotOutput("plotgraph2"),
                            plotOutput("plotgraph3")
                            )
                          )
                )
  )
)
)
s <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  set.seed(1234)
  pt1 <- qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("red"),binwidth=0.2,title="plotgraph1")
  pt3 <- qplot(rnorm(600),fill=I("blue"),binwidth=0.2,title="plotgraph3")
  pt2 <- reactive({
    input$do2
    if (input$do2){
      return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("blue"),binwidth=0.2,title="plotgraph2"))
    } else {
      return(NULL)
    }
  })
  output$plotgraph1 = renderPlot({pt1})
  output$plotgraph2 = renderPlot({pt2()})
  output$plotgraph3 = renderPlot({pt3}
  )
})

shinyApp(u,s)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one. +1 for you :)

Comment: He should have given me a +1 as well. And you for that matter.

Comment: Is it possible to divide it into 4 equal parts and have a 2 by 2 matrix with 4 plots?

Comment: @liza, actually yes it's possible. You just need to use fluidRow(
                verticalLayout(
                splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), plotOutput("distPlot"), plotOutput("distPlot2")),
                splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), plotOutput("distPlot3"), plotOutput("distPlot4"))

Comment: super useful for my use case of a DataTable and a plot side by side where grid.arrange() won't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Well, you did not exactly give us a complete example, but I think this is what you want:

#### ui.r

```
# ui.R

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel"),

  sidebarLayout(position = "left",
    sidebarPanel("sidebar panel",
      checkboxInput("do2", "Make 2 plots", value = T)
      ),
      mainPanel("main panel",
        fluidRow(
          column(6,plotOutput(outputId="plotgraph1", width="300px",height="300px")),  
          column(6,plotOutput(outputId="plotgraph2", width="300px",height="300px"))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

#### server.r

```
# server.r

library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) 
  {
  set.seed(1234)
  pt1 <- qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("red"),binwidth=0.2,title="plotgraph1")
    pt2 <- reactive({
      input$do2
      if (input$do2){
        return(qplot(rnorm(500),fill=I("blue"),binwidth=0.2,title="plotgraph2"))
      } else {
        return(NULL)
      }
    })
    output$plotgraph1 = renderPlot({pt1})
    output$plotgraph2 = renderPlot({pt2()})
  }
)
```

## Output

#### "Make 2 plots" checked:

[image]

#### "Make 2 plots" unchecked:

[image]