# How to layout 2 rows followed by 1 column with renderPlot in rmarkdown html_notebook with runtime shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, rnotebook

Consider the following rmarkdown html_notebook example:

````
---
output: html_notebook
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

blank1 <- renderPlot({ ggplot() + labs(title = "Plot 1") })
blank2 <- renderPlot({ ggplot() + labs(title = "Plot 2") })
blank3 <- renderPlot({ ggplot() + labs(title = "Plot 3") })

column(6, blank1, blank2)
column(6, blank3)
```
````

I would like to have the plots display as:

[image: plot-layout]

I have tried a few things including:

```
fluidRow(
  column(6, blank1, blank2),
  column(6, blank3)
)
```

But I have not been able to get `Plot 3` to span multiple rows.

---

Additional Notes (per comments):

- I would welcome a `cowplot` or `patchwork` solution, but I require reactivity from `shiny` (e.g. `ggplot(aes(x = input$var_select)) + ...`.
- Ideally, I would like to leverage `column()` and/or `fluidRow()` to keep of the responsive-design aspects.

Comment: You don't want to just put all the plots in one gridded image together, like with `cowplot` or `patchwork`, and then just render that one plot?

Comment: @camille I don’t believe I can because I would like some interactivity which requires a reactive/shiny.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns maybe this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384907/how-can-put-multiple-plots-side-by-side-in-shiny-r) could help?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. You can render a single `ggplot` based on reactive inputs, so you should be able to render a `ggplot` made up of other plots based on reactive inputs as well

Comment: @camille Unfortunately, I do not think it's that simple. When I attempt to just "add" the plots together (i.e., pathwork), I receieve `Error in blank1 + blank2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`. I have opened [this issue](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/issues/87#issue-391956918). Moreover, using `fluidRow` and/or `column` has some additional benefits for responsive design that I would not achieve using `cowplot` or `patchwork`.

Comment: Got it. Maybe you can add detail to the question on the responsiveness needs of the project

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this by passing the heights into the `renderPlot` explicitly. I am still very interested in other solutions:

```
blank1 <- renderPlot({ ggplot() + labs(title = "Plot 1") }, height = 200)
blank2 <- renderPlot({ ggplot() + labs(title = "Plot 2") }, height = 200)
blank3 <- renderPlot({ ggplot() + labs(title = "Plot 3") }, height = 400)

fluidRow(
  column(6, fluidRow(blank1), fluidRow(blank2)),
  column(6, fluidRow(blank3))
)
```

It's not perfect from a responsive design approach, but it'll work.

[image: Shiny with Plot Heights]

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following which sets the margins on the plot and columns to 0 and sets the heights of plot 3 to be twice that of plots 1 and 2.

````
---
output: html_notebook
runtime: shiny
---

<!-- break between code folding button and fluid layout -->
<br>

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

# create the plots telling ggplot to use 0 margins

p1 <- ggplot() +
      theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"),
            panel.background=element_rect(fill = "lightgreen"))
p2 <- ggplot() +
      theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"),
            panel.background=element_rect(fill = "lightblue"))
p3 <- ggplot() +
      theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"),
            panel.background=element_rect(fill = "orange"))

# Set the heights in renderPlot so that plot 3 is twice the height
# of the other 2 plots

blank1 <- renderPlot({p1}, height=200)
blank2 <- renderPlot({p2}, height=200)
blank3 <- renderPlot({p3}, height=400)

# Tell the fluid layout to set padding and margin to 0 for the column divs

fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6, blank1, blank2, offset=0, style='padding:0px;margin:0px;'),
    column(6, blank3, offset=0, style='padding:0px;margin:0px;')
  )
)
```
````

Which results in the following:

[image]